# How do you know when to release references to Outlook.MailItems when tracking events?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I need to track when attachments are added/deleted to/from mail items. In order to do this reliably I need to maintain a reference to the MailItem I have added the event handler to.

This all works great except I do not know when I can remove the reference.

I am currently handling this by using an Outlook.Inspector wrapper so I can remove my reference when the Inspector closes. The problem is that it appears that the Items displayed in the explorer are not in an inspector and so if a user replies to one of theses emails with out opening it in its own inspector I will not be notified if an attachment is added.

I am now looking at adding an event handler to the explorer to track which item is currently selected.

So my main question is if there is a better way to approach this problem?

Originally I was adding my event handlers in an ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler which allows me to track all events but then there is no way to know when the references can be freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Explorer.InlineResponse` and `Explorer.InlineResponseClose` events for that.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me some time.